# OpenCV stitcher mode:SCANS crashes with certain properties

Tags: c++, ios, opencv3.0, objective-c++

I am trying to setup a planar image stitching app, but if I give the stitcher below a PlaneWarper, the app crashes with a bad access exception. I also learned that ORB feature finding is best for planar stitching, but using an OrbFeatureFinder also causes the app to crash within the stitch function. I know I am not fully aware of how the stitching pipeline works, so if someone could help me understand the issue here, I would be grateful.

```
vector<Mat> imgs;

cv::Mat stitch (vector<Mat>& images)
{
    imgs = images;

    Mat pano;
    Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(Stitcher::SCANS, true);
    stitcher->setPanoConfidenceThresh(0.8f);
    stitcher->setFeaturesMatcher(makePtr<cv::detail::AffineBestOf2NearestMatcher>(true, true, 0.8f));
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(imgs, pano);

    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
    {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status) << endl;
        //return 0;
    }
    return pano;
}
```

I have tested on my Mac the stitching_detailed program with Orb feature finding and Planar warping, and it gave me great results, so I attempted to run stitching_detailed.cpp in the iOS app interface, but that cause all types of crashes, so I am trying this way now.

The stitching works well, but there is some distortion here and there and using the ORB feature finding with the Planar warping eliminated it on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I only did a cursory look, but I suspect your issue lies with how OpenCV is structured. When running on a Mac, it can utilize the GPU via OpenCL. However, when running on an iOS device, it cannot use OpenCL since it is unsupported. Because of this, it must use the CPU based implementation found here.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/808ba552c532408bddd5fe51784cf4209296448a/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp

You will see the variable `try_use_gpu` used extensively, and based on the way it configures and runs, this is likely the culprit. While I cannot say for certain in your case, I have found previously that there is iOS specific functionality that is broken, or simply even non-existant. With that said, you may want to file an issue with the project in the hope that someone can pick it up and fix it.

Comment: I messed with the GPU flag, and it doesn't seem to matter, it just looks like the specific classes I'm trying to use are broken in iOS, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Use open cv 2.4.9 version of stitching for iOS app. Also, use this code it will work great for iOS App

https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch

I already spend too much time to fixed the crash but now it got fixed.